# retrieving data from variable with name variableX - Java

Tags: java, loops, object, variables

For a uni assignment I am required to create a program in Java that manages 3 albums. I want to list information about these albums using a for loop to condense my code however, we are not allowed to use arrays. Is there a way to access a variable like albumX e.g

```
for (X=1;X<=3;X++)
{
    System.out.println("Album 1 is called" + albumX.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare multiple variables in for loop Example
  This Java Example shows how to declare multiple variables in Java For loop using
  declaration block.

```
public class DeclaringMultipleVariablesInForLoopExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Multiple variables can be declared in declaration block of for loop.
     */

     for(int i=0, j=1, k=2 ; i<5 ; i++)
       System.out.println("I : " + i + ",j : "+ j + ", k : " + k);

     /*
      * Please note that the variables which are declared, should be of same type
      * as in this example int.
      */  

      //THIS WILL NOT COMPILE
      //for(int i=0, float j; i < 5; i++);
  }
}
```